# Having diffuculties with discord bot. Using JS

Tags: javascript, discord

Currently i have it set-up like this

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ms = require("ms");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    pan1 =  "./pans/pan1.jpg"; pan2 = "./pans/pan2,jpg"; pan3 = "./pans/pan3.png"
    var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (msg.include (`cook`)); {
        number = 3
    }
    var random = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    switch (random) {
        case 1: message.channel.send({files: [pan1]}); break;
        case 2: message.channel.send({files: [pan2]}); break;
        case 3: message.channel.send({files: [pan3]}); break;
    } 
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "pan"
}
```

What i'm trying to do is have it so whenever someone does the command /pan it will send an image from the list however i'm constantly getting this error

https://gyazo.com/d9aa615eb4e76db8c68cf608c490a460

Do apologise if i layed this out poorly first time posting here and kind of a **giant noob at this.**

Comment: Try `msg.indexOf('cook') != -1` instead. You'll also need to get rid of the `;` before the `{`

Comment: The String object type does not have an `include` method, use `indexOf` or another way of matching (as commented above).

Comment: @lem it does in ES6 but that clearly isn't available here

Comment: @NickA huh, TIL. Thanks! (btw, its `includes` not `include` )

Comment: @lemieuxster bah, of course it is >.<, it may well be available then (indeed it is available with newer versions of node, my discord bot apparently uses it, can't remember writing that though)

Comment: Aah thank you so much for the help guys. I've asked at other places but no one was able to put it in simpler terms such as you guys. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

thats easy you did some miss spelling

```
if (msg.includes(`cook`)); {
        number = 3
}
```